# $(window).click in IE doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Why is it $(window).click doesn't work in IE. It works is all other browsers. (I can't use body or document in my page since something else in the page interferes with it.

```
$(window).click(function() {
        do stuff
    });
```

Comment: Huh? How do you do that?

Comment: You can "accept" an answer to [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/475311/meijioro#questions-table)  by clicking the large checkmark to the left of the answer that was most helpful (if any).

Comment: and welcome to the community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is simply not supported in IE.

[Here's a compatibility list](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html) of browsers' support for the `click` event.

You'll see that IE does not support it on the `window`.

I'd be curious to know what you mean when you say *"I can't use body or document in my page since something else in the page interferes with it."*

Comment: There is another module on the page (was built by someone else and is complex so I don't want to mess with it) and whenever an animation happens in it it interferes with the function in my module I am trying to build.

Comment: @meijiOrO: I see. Unfortunately as you can see, binding to the `window` simply won't be an option for IE.

Answer (score 9):

try $(document).click(........

Comment: True, except that the question states that `document` can not be used in this situation.

Comment: for me that helped either way ;)