# hide on window and other element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button its id is `tools` onclick it show a menu with some links and with click on other places of the page this menu will be hidden.

Every think work well but the menu don't hide when I click on the buttons (`#up,#del,#tools`)

```
$('#tools').click(function(){
    var ofset = $(this).offset();
    $('#moreMenu').css({'top':(ofset.top+35),'left':ofset.left,'display':'',});
    return false;
});

$(window).click(function(){$('#moreMenu').hide();});

    <div id='moreMenu' style='width:250px;background-color:#f0f0f0;border:2px solid gray;height:100px;position:absolute;display:none;'>some menu</div>

<button id='up' title='up'  >‍<img src='../images/beta/up.png'></button>

<button id='del' title='del'  >‍<img src='../images/beta/delete.png'></button>

<button id='tools' title='tools' style='width:70px;' >‍<img src='../images/beta/tools.png' style='margin-right:30%;'></button>
```

**How can be hide on every elements!?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the click event on **html**. It'll let you hide the div when you click anywhere inside the page.

```
$("html").click(function(){$('#moreMenu').hide();});
```

OR,

```
$(document).click(function(){$('#moreMenu').hide();});
```

[**A Thread  Reference:** $(window).click(..); not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820863/window-click-in-ie-doesnt-work)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/5eAvP/)

Comment: thatnk you
but this worked better for me `$('window,html').click(function(){$('#moreMenu').hide();});`

Comment: $(window).click(..); isn't supported in IE. That's why i preferred a general solution. You can try another way like, $(document).click(..); . Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to add javascript to hide the menu when the buttons are pressed.

```
$("button").click(function(){$('#moreMenu').hide();});
```

Comment: i need both button and window
with this the window dont working!!